# Splitting in multiple columns values that are separated by a comma

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have the following dataset

```
Chr     Position       Name      AD                                 
1       866511          A       13,21
1       881627          A       28,33
2       1599812         B       67,25
```

I need to split the column AD into three columns `[REF, ALT1, ALT2]`.
When for every row the AD has only two values I still need the ALT2 column filled in with NaN value.

The following code works if AD contains rows with three values

```
df['REF'], df['ALT1'], df['ALT2'] = df['AD'].str.split(',', 2).str
```

However, in some cases for each row, the dataset contains only two values in column `AD` and when I run the same line I get the following error message:

`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)`

In this case, I would like to still have the third column `ALT2` and fill it in with `NaN` values. Any suggestion? Thank you, anyone, who is willing to help.

Comment: If you know that you will only have either 3 or 2, you could use an if statement (or a try catch) to go through the two options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `add` an extra `','`

```
df['REF'], df['ALT1'], df['ALT2'] = zip(*df.AD.add(',').str.split(',').str[:3])

df

   Chr  Position Name        AD REF ALT1 ALT2
0    1    866511    A     13,21  13   21     
1    1    881627    A  28,33,31  28   33   31
2    2   1599812    B     67,25  67   25
```

Or without altering `df`

```
df.assign(**dict(zip('REF ALT1 ALT2'.split(), zip(*df.AD.add(',').str.split(',').str[:3]))))

   Chr  Position Name        AD REF ALT1 ALT2
0    1    866511    A     13,21  13   21     
1    1    881627    A  28,33,31  28   33   31
2    2   1599812    B     67,25  67   25
```

Comment: piRSquared thank you so much, you fixed it so quickly and it worked great for me. I've only added `print(df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True))` to fill in the empty spaces with NaN.

Answer (score 1):

you can set the parameter `expand` to `True` and then do the job with:

```
df['REF'], df['ALT1'], df['ALT2'] = df.AD.str.split(',', 2, expand=True).values.T
```

I added a row with 3 values in the column AD with `df.loc[3,:] = [3,5432,'C', '32,45,65']` and you get:

```
   Chr   Position Name        AD REF ALT1  ALT2
0  1.0   866511.0    A     13,21  13   21  None
1  1.0   881627.0    A     28,33  28   33  None
2  2.0  1599812.0    B     67,25  67   25  None
3  3.0     5432.0    C  32,45,65  32   45    65
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `rename` and `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat((df, df['AD'].str.split(',', expand=True)
                            .rename(columns={0:'REF',1:'ALT1',2:'ALT2'})
               ), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   Chr  Position Name     AD REF ALT1
0    1    866511    A  13,21  13   21
1    1    881627    A  28,33  28   33
2    2   1599812    B  67,25  67   25
```

Comment: Quang Hoang I would still need the ALT2 column. PiRSquared worked really well. Thank you all!